# Извлечь текст субтитров из видеофайла

Tags: python, видео

Передо мной стоит задача: извлечь из большого числа видеофайлов субтитры.

Насколько я понимаю, субтитры где-то внутри видеофайла хранятся тупо текстом. Есть ли какие-то библиотеки для питона, которые позволяют извлечь текст субтитров из видеофайла?

Хотелось бы универсального решения для всех популярных видеоформатов (avi, mkv, mp4 итп). Но если посоветуете разные библиотеки для разных форматов, то это тоже поможет мне.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для подобных целей хорошо подходит [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). Он поддерживает большую часть современных видеоформатов, с которыми можно ознакомиться [тут](http://ffmpeg.org/general.html#Video-Codecs).

Вызов FFmpeg производится из командной строки или терминала. Для этого достаточно ввести следующую команду:

```
ffmpeg -i SampleFile.SampleExtension -map 0:s:0 SubtitleName.srt
```

Также есть готовое решение для [MKV](https://github.com/jorti/extract-subs/blob/master/extract-subs.py).

*P.S.* Вызов команды в Python осуществляется так:

```
os.system('Your Command')`
```